# Using attributes for bitmap src inside a drawable selector

Tags: android

I'm trying to create custom themes for my app and therefore, would like the selector to pick up the right drawable based on the current theme. Unfortunately, doesn't look like any image gets picked up at all.

This is my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <bitmap android:src="?attr/test_a"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <bitmap android:src="?attr/test_a"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <bitmap android:src="?attr/test_a"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="?attr/test_b"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

My attributes are defined in attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="test_a" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="test_b" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

And my theme has the following:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="test_a">@drawable/test_a_dark</item>
    <item name="test_b">@drawable/test_b_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Light">
    <item name="test_a">@drawable/test_a_light</item>
    <item name="test_b">@drawable/test_b_light</item>
</style>
```

The theme is applied in the manifest as required. I have seen some questions on SO around this saying that there's a problem Pre-Lolipop, however, I'm testing on Marshmellow.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why this happens but in case this is useful for someone, as a workaround I did the following:

1) Created two selectors - one for the dark theme, pointing directly at the dark drawables, and one for the light theme

2) Created one attribute with type reference

3) Modified the theme to use that attribute point at the selector instead of the drawable